# SP2013 and site URL/Wildcard Cert Question

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, iis, certificate

So as stated in the last question, I inherited a pretty rough SP2013 environment and have been working through various issues to keep it stable before moving everything to SP Online.

So my question is this: we have various WebApps: 
https://webapp01.olddomain.com 
https://webapp02.olddomain.com

and the previous admin used a CA provided wildcard cert for *olddomain.com for SSL.

Now the organization decided not to renew this cert as it has an old domain name attached to it, instead, they got a similar wildcard for *newdomain.com.

My question is, is there a way to have all the webapps/sites/subsites renamed from https://webapp01.olddomain.com to https://webapp01.newdomain.com so this cert can be used?

From everything Ive seen it looks like all the sites/subsites need to be reconfigured to point to the new URL which if that is the case, I will probably just make a case to renew the old cert in the interest of keeping things simple since we will be migrating anyway. Thanks for any info as always.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest extending the Web App to a different URL, you can then apply the new SSL cert to the new IIS site.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/extend-a-claims-based-web-application